# Issue with ® symbol crashing IDLE

Tags: python

I am doing an assessment for university where we have to scrape websites and display the information using TKinter. The website I am using uses the ® symbol instead the HTML code for ®. Every time I run my code, IDLE crashes. I am wondering if anyone knows a way around this issue.

```
    from urllib import urlopen
    from re import findall
    from Tkinter import *
    from HTMLParser import *

    games_window = Tk()
    games_window.title('Top 10 Games Specials')
    games_window.geometry('1000x1000')


    games_contents = urlopen("http://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1").read()
    gam_info = findall('<img src="([\w\.:/]*.jpg[?t=0-9]*)[a-z\s?="<>/_]*([\w\.\-\(\) \':$&!®]*)[a-z\s/<>="_]*([\w ,]*)[\w\s/<>="&-;%#]*([0-9\.$]*)[\w\s/<>]*([0-9\.$]*)',games_contents)

    info01 = Label(games_window, text = gam_info[0][1], font=("Courier", 15), relief=SUNKEN)

    info01.place(x = 230, y = 450)

    games_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post a minimal code snippet that reproduces the problem, along with the actual error message (not "it crashes").

Comment: It doesn't show an error message. IDLE freezes up and closes

But this is the code I am using.    'games_contents = urlopen("http://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1").read()
    gam_info = findall('<img src="([\w\.:/]*.jpg[?t=0-9]*)[a-z\s?="<>/_]*([\w\.\-\(\) \':$&!®]*)[a-z\s/<>="_]*([\w ,]*)[\w\s/<>="&-;%#]*([0-9\.$]*)[\w\s/<>]*([0-9\.$]*)',games_contents)'

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your question to include the code. It doesn't really work in a comment.

Comment: And please include `import` statements etc: ideally, you should make a snippet that we can just paste into IDLE and try out.

Comment: It might also help to include the Python version and the OS it is running on. I just cut-and-pasted your ® into `x='®'; print(x)` and it worked fine on my system (Python 2.7.8 on Linux).

Comment: "Freezes up and closes". How long between freeze and close? Does control/C get out of the freeze? Can you watch the Python process from another window with some system utility (such as `ps` on linux) to see if it's in a loop gobbling memory? I'm thinking maybe some sort of infinite loop ending badly when the system runs out of memory.

Comment: What exactly makes you think it's the (r) symbol anyway?

Comment: @nigel222 some other students have used the ® without issue... with the same OS (windows 8.1) and python 2.7.11. It freezes for about 10 seconds and then closes. nothing I do changes the situation.

Comment: @Blorgbeard When i remove the ® symbol the code runs but obviously stops once the regex reaches the ®

Comment: But I did a work around and it seems to be working.

old code - ([\w\.\-\(\) \':$&!®]*)

new code - ([^<&]*)

Thank you both for your time with the help you provided